# Editable UITabbar like Configure Page on Youtube for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, youtube, uitabbarcontroller

I'd like to know how to make customable menu icon 
(like Youtube for iPhone or other iOS Device.When you enter More > Edit > Configure Page and you can edit any menu on tabbar as you prefer)

I think I should make some UIView ,that will be call via "present modal" method , concern about editable Menu Icon with Drag Drop Menu positioning.then it's done I'll save data about menu position in some data persistence. and use this data to rearrange Tabbar Layout.

so, any suggestion or hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is setting the TabBarController's customizableViewControllers.

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray array]; // your VCs
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers; // all VCs can be rearranged by the user
```

Note that this is **not** persistent.
Check [Erica's tutorial](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C05-ViewControllers/07-Persistent%20Tab%20Bars) on that, it might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.By the way I can open your links (Erica's tutorial). can you give me some other stuff ?

Comment: Absolutely Work for me !! Thank you very much Jenox !! :D

Comment: By the way,Did Android platform have something like customizable Tabbar on iOS? (I may implement this stuff on both platfom)